# A package exists in dpkg but it can't be installed via apt

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

My goal is to check if a package has been installed, and if not, install it.

A package exists:

```
dpkg -l | grep arangodb3
rc  arangodb3    3.4.11-1  amd64     a multi-model NoSQL database
```

But:

```
$ sudo apt remove arangodb3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'arangodb3' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 46 not upgraded.
```

How can this be?  And how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rc` status at the start of the `dpkg -l` output means that the package is already removed, but its configuration remains. So `apt remove` has nothing to do.

You can remove it entirely by purging its configuration:

```
sudo apt purge arangodb3
```

> My goal is to check if a package has been installed, and if not, install it.

Then you probably should just install it: if it’s already installed, it won’t be re-installed (although it will be upgraded if necessary), if it’s not, it will be.

To determine whether a package is correctly installed, run

```
dpkg-query -W -f '${db:Status-Status}' package
```

(replacing `package` as appropriate). If this outputs `installed`, the package is installed; anything else means it’s not (or not fully).

Comment: then how do I take into account presence/absense of "rc"? Or rather, how do I check if a package is installed regardless of whether or not its config-n remains?

Comment: A package is fully installed if `dpkg -l` shows `ii` at the start of the line, or rather, `i` in the second column. An non-installed package should not show up in `dpkg -l`’s output at all.

Comment: how do I make dpkg give me a binary response - package info or empty string -  and ignore its config-n presense?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: `dpkg-query -W -f '${db:Status-Status}' "nginx"` -- nothing, although it's installed fully, with `ii`.

Comment: OK, what does `dpkg-query -W -f '${Status}' nginx` show?