# How to find an installed package, if it exists, by precise name?

Tags: bash, grep, package-management, dpkg

I want to check whether or not a package has been installed. I need a precise match.

There will find the packages that start with nginx

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -w 'nginx'
ii  nginx                                1.18.0-0ubuntu1                   all          small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server
ii  nginx-common                         1.18.0-0ubuntu1                   all          small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server - common files
ii  nginx-core                           1.18.0-0ubuntu1                   amd64        nginx web/proxy server (standard version)

$ dpkg -l | grep -w 'nginx$'

$ dpkg -l | grep -w "nginx"
ii  nginx                                1.18.0-0ubuntu1                   all          small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server
ii  nginx-common                         1.18.0-0ubuntu1                   all          small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server - common files
ii  nginx-core                           1.18.0-0ubuntu1                   amd64        nginx web/proxy server (standard version)

$ dpkg -l | grep -w "\<nginx\>"
ii  nginx                                1.18.0-0ubuntu1                   all          small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server
ii  nginx-common                         1.18.0-0ubuntu1                   all          small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server - common files
ii  nginx-core                           1.18.0-0ubuntu1                   amd64        nginx web/proxy server (standard version)

$ dpkg -l | grep  "\<nginx\>"
ii  nginx                                1.18.0-0ubuntu1                   all          small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server
ii  nginx-common                         1.18.0-0ubuntu1                   all          small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server - common files
ii  nginx-core                           1.18.0-0ubuntu1                   amd64        nginx web/proxy server (standard version)
```

whereas I want nginx only. How to fix it?

Comment: As you only want the exact match, maybe check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576292/display-exact-matches-only-with-grep).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [A package exists in dpkg but it can't be installed via apt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/637376/86440), use `dpkg-query`:

```
dpkg-query -W -f '${db:Status-Status}' nginx
```

This will show “installed” if, and only if, the `nginx` package, and only that package, is fully installed.

If `dpkg-query` doesn’t work for you, specify the package as an argument to `dpkg -l`:

```
dpkg -l nginx
```

Comment: `dpkg-query -W -f '${db:Status-Status}' "nginx"` -- nothing, although it's installed fully, with `ii`.

Comment: How about `dpkg -l nginx`?

Answer (score 0):

By filtering the output of `dpkg -l`:

```
dpkg -l | awk /^ii/'{print $2}' | grep -w nginx$
```

The same results with (`sudo apt install dctrl-tools`) :

```
grep-status -FStatus -sPackage -n  "install ok installed" |grep -w  nginx$
```

Comment: Why would you use grep if you're already filtering with awk? Just print if the second field is what you need: `dpkg -l | awk /^ii/ && $2=="nginx"` or even `dpkg -l | awk '$1=="ii" && $2=="nginx"`.

Comment: A single `grep` should suffice : `grep -E '^ii\s+nginx '` filter well

Comment: `dpkg -l` can filter on its own, no need for `grep` or `awk`.